# iOS - UIWebview - data cutoff at the bottom

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am loading the html data in UIWebview, and i made the webview.scrollview.pagingEnabled = true.
But when I scroll the page, The Bottom and Top the text is cut off.

Please suggest how to resolve this problem.

[image]
Thanks,
Bharathi

Comment: what do you expect?

Comment: This last line should not be visible,

Comment: is it possible to tell me the url you are loading into the webview to test it?

Comment: I am loading an epub doc into the webview